# Tilde Expansion Doesn't Work in Docker CMD Command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tilde-expansion

I have a Dockerfile with the following line:

```
USER lodgepole

CMD ["tail", "-f", "~/block.txt"]
```

But container exits with error that the file `~/block.txt` is not found

The following does work as expected:

```
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/home/lodgepole/block.txt"]
```

Is this a bug in Docker or is there a limitation related to tilde expansion that I'm not aware of?

Using Docker 20.10.9 on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tilde expansion is done by the shell. When you use the *exec* form of CMD, there is no shell to do the expansion.

You can use the *shell* form of CMD instead, which runs the command through a shell, like this

```
CMD tail -f ~/block.txt
```

or you can use the *exec* form and run the shell explicitly, like this

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "tail -f ~/block.txt"]
```

The two commands do the exact same thing. If you use the *shell* form, it'll run the shell in the same way that the *exec* form does.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd